# Combining one webpage section into other webpage

Tags: php, html, css

I have downloaded a several nulled website templates for testing purposes.
I was wondering if I could combine them into one webpage?

For example, take category page layout from one webpage and implement it to other webpage. Is it possible to create webpage using php and html files combined, lets say index.html and contact.php?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> YES, you can. But, it's fairly not easy though.

When you are combining two different templates, each have seperate `stylesheets` and possible `Javascript/JQuery` scripts, which conflicts between the two.

And you can combine php and html files in same file.

Just use `<?php` at the beginning of php code and `?>` at the end of php code.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank You very much, it helps a lot.  :)

Comment: Please upvote my answer and mark as accepted if it helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's just a matter of copying the section of code from one file and pasting it in the other. Which is why templates are available in the first place. But notice that you can't go copying PHP code and placubgit in a .html file.

Comment: Thank You for Your fast answer. But, regarding html and php files, I know I cant do that, but can my webpage use html and php files at the same time. Lets say my home page would be written in html, so it would be home.html, and my categories like contact, news, popular would be contact.php, popular.php news.php, and not like contact.html news.html...

Comment: @TroubleZero How can you say that you can't have php and html in single file?

Comment: @Labros you can have both php and html in single file. Please check my answer

Comment: Yes you can use both PHP and HTML files. But just know that all HTML is viable in PHP, so why not jsut have only PHP files since having HTML in the PHP file is perfectly allowed.